# How does "layout_constraintHeight_min" work?

Tags: android-constraintlayout

I want a view to always occupy all the available height with a minimum of 30% (the minimum must be a percentage to accomodate different screen ratios).

I have tried the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/textView11"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.3"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_min="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textView10"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The height of `textView11` is always exactly 30%; it never expands further to occupy the available space (try different values for `layout_constraintHeight_percent` in the second view or even delete the first one).

What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: You will have to do this programmatically.